# filter outpout of process with potentially unlimted output, detect exit code and timeout after X

Tags: python, django, subprocess, uwsgi

I have some existing **Django** code running under **uwsgi** (under **Linux**) with **threading disabled**, that executes for some requests a subprocess, that I don't have any control over.

The normal operation is following:

- the subprocess runs for a rather short time and returns either an exit code of 0 or something different. The code will write some messages to stdout / stderr. The return code (exit code) will tell me whether the work was done correctly. if execution failed it would be good to gather stdout/stderr and log it to understand why things failed.

On rare occasions however the subprocess can encounter a so far not understood race condition and will do following.

- it will write repeatedly a specific message to stdout and stderr and loop and hang forever.

As I don't know whether there are any other race conditions, that could freeze the process with or without any output. Id' also like to add a timeout. (Though a solution, that adresses getting the return code and detecting the repeated message would be already a good achievement.

What I tried so far is:

```
import os
import select
import subprocess
import time

CMD = ["bash", "-c", "echo hello"]
def run_proc(cmd=CMD, timeout=10):
    """ run a subprocess, fetch (and analyze stdout / stderr) and
        detect if script runs too long
        and exit when script finished
    """

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout = proc.stdout.fileno()
    stderr = proc.stderr.fileno()

    t0 = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - t0 > timeout:
            print("TIMEOUT")
            break
        rc = proc.returncode
        print("RC", rc)
        if proc.returncode is not None:
            break
        to_rd, to_wr, to_x = select.select([stdout, stderr], [], [], 2)
        print(to_rd, to_wr, to_x)
        if to_rd:
            if stdout in to_rd:
                rdata = os.read(stdout, 100)
                print("S:", repr(rdata))
            if stderr in to_rd:
                edata = os.read(stderr, 100)
                print("E:", repr(edata))
    print(proc.returncode)
```

In fact I don't need stdout and stderr to be handled separately, but this didn't change anything

However when the subprocess finished its output something really strange happens.

```
the output of select tells me, that stdout and stderr can be read from, but when I read I get an empty string.
proc.returncode is still None
```

How could I fix my above code  or how could I save my problem in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check at least on [Popen.poll()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll):

```
def run_proc(cmd=CMD, timeout=10):
    """ run a subprocess, fetch (and analyze stdout / stderr) and
        detect if script runs too long
        and exit when script finished
    """

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout = proc.stdout.fileno()
    stderr = proc.stderr.fileno()

    t0 = time.time()
    while True:
        returncode = proc.poll()
        print("RC", returnode)
        if returncode is not None:
            break

        if time.time() - t0 > timeout:
            print("TIMEOUT")
            # You need to kill the subprocess, break doesn't stop it!
            proc.terminate()
            # wait for the killed process to 'reap' the zombie
            proc.wait()
            break

        to_rd, to_wr, to_x = select.select([stdout, stderr], [], [], 2)
        print(to_rd, to_wr, to_x)
        if to_rd:
            if stdout in to_rd:
                rdata = os.read(stdout, 100)
                print("S:", repr(rdata))
            if stderr in to_rd:
                edata = os.read(stderr, 100)
                print("E:", repr(edata))
    print(returncode)
```

Out:

```
RC None
[3] [] []
S: b'hello\n'
RC None
[3, 5] [] []
S: b''
E: b''
0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. `proc.poll()` helps me.

However
`while proc.poll() is None and proc.returncode is None:`

I think could be changed to
`while proc.poll():`

or perhaps to `while True:` followed by `rc = proc.poll()`, and somewhere an `if rc is not None: break`

Comment: another issue.

`proc.terminate()` seems to leave a zombie. Any way to avoid this. as uwsgi is running for a very long time, there is the theoretical risk of leaving quite some zombies behind

Comment: `proc.terminate()` followed by `proc.wait()` seems to fix the zombie issue

Comment: I upped your answer.

Could you please adapt your answer so that
`proc.terminate()` and `proc.wait()` is called 

and perhaps change the while statement to make it clearer that
the result of `proc.poll()` is `proc.returncode`

Or if you prefer I could add these changes to your answer and then mark this answer as solution

Comment: @gelonida: Edit my answer please.

Comment: I slightly adapted and accepted your answer. `proc.poll()` was what I was missing. Thanks